# ruby script/server ERROR missing msvcrt-ruby191.dll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dll

Hi i have a small problem, first of all im trying to run a ruby-on-rails project on the XAMP server ever time i try to run the "ruby script/server" command a messege window appears saying that im missing msvcrt-ruby191.dll

and the command prompt output looks something like this

```
d:\umer\lightfantasticapp>ruby script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- geokit-rails (MissingSourceFile)

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

from d:/umer/lightfantasticapp/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/init.rb:1:in`evaluate_init_rb'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/libinitializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/libinitializer.rb:165:in `process'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'

from d:/umer/lightfantasticapp/config/environment.rb:11

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'

from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'

from script/server:3
```

kindly help me, ive even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the frame work, i tried to install the geokit, sql, gem as well but none of that worked for me... any suggetions..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is thrown if a gem installed is compiled against 1.9.1 ruby which you don't have installed

As you see the error is thrown while trying to require a gem
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29

I would guess it is either json or mysql gem (do you use mysql?)

the solution is to uninstall the gem and install it with the --platform=ruby flag
gem uninstall json
gem install json --platform=ruby -v=1.4.6